# How do I use tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) with sections

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I use sections to load messages(viewForFooterInSection) and rows to load the reply of specific messages if any.

Previously I was using a long press gesture on the tableView to detect a touch on the tableView and return the indexPath using tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint), however I have not found a similar method to get indexPath of long pressed cell

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are going for cell-level gesture when you have already achieved getting indexPath using gesture on tableview. In case you are trying to get cell from indexPath then you can try like

```
guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return }
```

Anyhow coming to answer for your question, we can do the following way to get indexPath from cell-level.

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: AnyObject {
func longPressAction(onCell: CustomCell)
```

}

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let lg = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))
    lg.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    lg.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    self.addGestureRecognizer(lg)
}

@objc func longPress(gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureReconizer.state != UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
        return
    }
    delegate?.longPressAction(onCell: self)
}
}
```

And in your tableview cell for row method, assign the delegate.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

And confirm to the CustomCellDelegate protocol in your viewController.

```
extension ViewController: CustomCellDelegate {
func longPressAction(onCell: CustomCell) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: onCell) else { return }
    print(indexPath.section, indexPath.row)
}
}
```